# How to find my GitHub username so that I can be found via the URL?

Tags: git, github

I'm confused about my GitHub username

1. Is it the one that is being displayed on the top right corner of the window?
2. Or is it the one I created using "git config --global user.name" from my shell?

I need to give it in a job application form.

Comment: are 1 and 2 different?

Comment: 1... The other is used in commit messages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: What would the employer do with the username you're using *in your own shell*?

Comment: A bit late, but I believe that this question *is* appropriate. While it is not a programming question directly, it deals with an important question regarding an important programming tool (like, for example, all the questions about Eclipse), which is clearly within SO's scope.

Comment: I think I agree @Binarus, I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The one displayed in the top right corner in GitHub is your *GitHub* username - this is the one you use to login to GitHub when you enter the site and when you commit over HTTPS, and the one that appears in the URLs of your GitHub repositories.

The one you create using `git config` is your *Git* username - this is the one that appears as the author of your commits when you do `git log` or `git blame`.

Since you can use Git outside of GitHub, those two usernames do not have to be the same.

Also, the GitHub username must be unique, but nothing forces uniqueness of Git usernames.

Comment: does for the user name, the email address part also counts, like if the email used to create a account is `abcd@gmail.com`, what is the username of the account is it `abcd` or `abcd@gmail.com`

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya `abcd` is the _Gmail_ username - not (necessarily) the _GitHub_ username. In GitHub's context the email - beside for contacting you - is used for matching Git commits with GitHub users. So `abcd@gmail.com` may be registered on some GitHub account(which could be named anything) and GitHub will mark the commits with this email as belonging to that account.

Comment: Someone in hurry, Official Link [Setting your username in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)

Comment: For anyone wondering, in order to SEE your username (as asked in the question's title actually...) you must do : `git config user.name` and for your email `git config user.email`